# Business Directory plugin: restricting title length

Tags: wordpress, directory, title

I use Business Directory plugin for directory website. I want to restrict title to 100 characters or fewer.

I tried in CSS to restrict, but this doesn't work:

```
case 'title':
    $value = sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="%s" >%s</a>',
                      get_permalink( $post_id ),
                      wpbdp_get_option( 'listing-link-in-new-tab' ) ? '_blank' : '_self',
                      get_the_title( $post_id ) );
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

`substr('get_the_title( $post_id )', 0, 100);`